# Meaning of 生じてきたことを喜ぶことのできる心の余裕を持ちたい

Tags: translation

From 林道義「父性の復権」(中央公論新社):

> 思春期というのは、より高いものを求める心理が強いので、親が十分に権威を持っているときでさえも、親以外のもっと尊敬できると思われる人物に傾倒し、それと比較して親を否定してくることがる。ましてや、親が十分に権威を持っていない場合には、子どもの反抗は必ず起こると言っても過言ではない。その場合には、他に具体的なモデルがなくても、親を不十分なモデルとして否定する気持ちが反抗として現れるのである。それは、より普遍的な価値を獲得しようという心の動きであるから、親は子どもの反抗に出会ったなら、そうしたより高いものを求める心が子どもに**生じてきたことを喜ぶことのできる心の余裕を持ちたいものである**。

I am struggling with the last sentence of the attached text.
The last line is where it gets really difficult for me, the 生じてきたことを喜ぶことのできる心の余裕を持ちたいものである.

I tried to translate this sentence, but especially this last part is not comprehensible for me. My attempt looks like this, but I am sure this misses the point:

> ...the (parent) should enable the child to develop space for carrying happiness in his heart

Could someone explain me what this sentence means?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the expression is done in a roundabout way (if not in gibberish.) I am convinced it should have been written in plain Japanese.

That said, I would translate

(親　は) --- 生じて きた こと を 喜ぶ こと の できる 心 の 余裕 を 持ちたい もの である

as

It is desirable that parents should take it easy and congratulate that their child has grown to show aspiration.

I know this is not naturally flowing, but I can't make up a satin purse out of a sow's ear.